# Ubuntu 17.10 - AMDGPU-PRO 17.50 with --px option cannot be installed because of missing package

Tags: 17.10, amd-graphics, switchable-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I tried installing AMDGPU-PRO without any settings then I can not log-in after rebooting. I searched through AskUbuntu and found one answer telling to try the --px option, which might be applicable to me since I have switchable graphics but it would not go through the installation and display something like this after getting repositories:

```
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro
```

The GPUs in my notebook are:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6/R7 Graphics]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Kaveri [Radeon R6/R7 Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get this package from the prevoius version of amdgpu-pro package. I did that this way:

- install amdgpu-pro 17.40
- copy directory /var/opt/amdgpu-local to /var/opt/amdgpu-local-17.40
- copy /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro.list to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro-17.40.list
- edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro-17.40.list so it points to a -17.40 directory in /var/opt/...
- unsinstall amdgpu-pro 17.40

Now you have local source of amdgpu-pro driver which has required package. You can now install amdgpu-pro 17.50 with -px option.

I've tried this solution. Though amdgpu-pro driver v17.50 was installed successfully with -px option, my system got into logon loop. I've struggled to cope with it for an hour or so, but haven't succeed, so I gave up for a while. My system is Lenovo ThinkPad E550 with Radeon R7 M265. Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS

But probably, it might work fine in your system. Not too much moves to give it a try, eh?